# How to add additional tags to csv import data at time of import

Tags: laravel, import, tags

Using a text input field I need to add tags to the records being imported via CSV import module. In the controller, I am automatically adding user id, team id, and timestamp to all imported records and now I need to add user-defined tags to all records at the time of import.

What do in need in my controller to achieve this functionality?

```
<?php

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SpreadsheetReader;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;


class CsvImportController extends Controller

{

public function parse(Request $request)
{

$file = $request->file('csv_file');
$request->validate([
    'csv_file' => 'mimes:csv,txt',
]);

$path      = $file->path();
$hasHeader = $request->input('header', false) ? true : false;

$reader  = new SpreadsheetReader($path);
$headers = $reader->current();
$lines   = [];
$lines[] = $reader->next();
$lines[] = $reader->next();


$filename = str_random(10) . '.csv';
$file->storeAs('csv_import', $filename);

$modelName     = $request->input('model', false);
$fullModelName = "App\\" . $modelName;

$model     = new $fullModelName();
$fillables = $model->getFillable();

$redirect = url()->previous();

return view('csvImport.parse_import',
    compact('headers', 'filename', 'fillables', 'hasHeader', 'modelName', 'lines', 'redirect'));

}

public function process(Request $request)

{

$filename = $request->input('filename', false);
$path     = storage_path('app/csv_import/' . $filename);

$hasHeader = $request->input('hasHeader', false);

$fields = $request->input('fields', false);
$fields = array_flip(array_filter($fields));

$modelName = $request->input('modelName', false);
$model     = "App\\" . $modelName;

$reader = new SpreadsheetReader($path);
$insert = [];

foreach ($reader as $key => $row) {
    if ($hasHeader && $key == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $tmp = [];
    foreach ($fields as $header => $k) {
        $tmp[$header] = $row[$k];
    }
    if (auth()->user()->team_id) {
        $tmp['created_by_id']      = auth()->user()->id;
        $tmp['created_by_team_id'] = auth()->user()->team_id;
        $tmp['created_at'] = now();
    }
    $insert[] = $tmp;

}

$for_insert = array_chunk($insert, 100);

foreach ($for_insert as $insert_item) {
    $model::insert($insert_item);
}

$rows  = count($insert);
$table = str_plural($modelName);

File::delete($path);

$redirect = $request->input('redirect', false);

return redirect()->to($redirect)->with('message', trans('global.app_imported_rows_to_table',
    ['rows' => $rows, 'table' => $table]));

}
```

**My View:**

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-12'>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            @lang('global.app_csvImport')
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.csv_process') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="{{ $filename }}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="hasHeader" value="{{ $hasHeader }}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="modelName" value="{{ $modelName }}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ $redirect }}"/>

                <table class="table">
                    @if (isset($headers))
                        <tr>
                            @foreach ($headers as $field)
                                <th>{{ $field }}</th>
                            @endforeach
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                    @if($lines)
                        @foreach ($lines as $line)
                            <tr>
                                @foreach ($line as $field)
                                    <td>{{ $field }}</td>
                                @endforeach
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                    <tr>
                        @foreach ($headers as $key => $header)
                            <td>
                                <select name="fields[{{ $key }}]">
                                    <option value=''>Please select</option>
                                    @foreach ($fillables as $k => $fillable)
                                        <option value="{{ $fillable }}"
                                                @if (strtolower($header) === strtolower($fillable)) selected @endif>{{ $fillable  }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-import">
                    @lang('global.app_import_data')
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-import2">
                    @lang('global.app_import_data')
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```